# Google Cloud SQL and ODBC

Tags: django, google-app-engine, jdbc, odbc

I understand that Google Cloud SQL can be access through JDBC externally, that's nice, but I have been using various SQL GUI clients to view and manage mostly MySQL databases.  Tools like Navicat, Sequel Pro, etc. are familiar to me.  Took a brief look at SQuirreL SQL Client, which Google mentioned, that uses JDBC, but it is yet another tool to learn, going backward instead of forward.  Also searched for ODBC-JDBC bridges, but most are expensive tools.

Any suggestion?  I just want to develop apps with Django and relational db, and not to deal with all these complexities.  Google App Engine and Cloud SQL seems promising, have been waiting for years for Django support and it is finally here, but this seems to be one missing link.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible using the IP connectivity. The [Admin and Reporting Tools](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin-tools) explains how to connect from GUI tools like MySQL Workbench and Toad.